# Help selecting an e commerce framework

Tags: craft3

So i have a client that wants fast e commerce store, currently I've narrowed it down to 2 solutions.

Headless Magneto CMS with a Magneto PWS studio as the front-end. Its based on react which should be fast and Magento's search uses elastic search which I've read is faster than MySQL.

The second is a simpler solution, Craft Commerce. Is a flexible and light commerce platform.

However how will a "light" PHP/MySQL platform compare to a react front-end with a "heavy" back-end using elastic search back-end.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of being too general/closed for off-topic, before you choose any platform, I would ask these questions:

- What **sort of functionality**  does your client require—now or in the future?
- What **kinds of products** will the store support (eg bundles, custom products, variants, donations, etc).
- What **sort of budget / developer support** can the client support or is required?

In general, Craft is the more nascent/new product so if your team's dev chops aren't familiar with Commerce, there can be a learning curve.

Magento does a lot of the box and if you need to hook into some obscure (or not so obscure) service, Magento probably already has a plugin for it. It has a bigger ecosystem but that doesn't mean Craft isn't up to the task.

Shopify can also be an option depending on what you're trying to do.

In general, Craft/Commerce really excels at customized e-commerce. If your client's needs are modest, for example selling simple products without customization, Shopify might actually be a better fit long term. However when you start to get into more niche businesses where there's customized shipping or products, the the tables tip more in favor of Craft.

## Speed

You question also asks about speed. `Fast` is a relative turn. A lot is going to depend on 1) server infrastructure and 2) your own code.

Also:

- What does a **performance budget** look like?
- How many **visitors/users** are you expecting? **Where** are they located?
- How will you **measure** the solution?

Compared to Magento, Craft is pretty light-weight. Magento is not known for being resource-friendly, however there is probably more documentation on how to make it speedy.

If you go with something like Shopify, you don't have to worry about infrastructure—which is one of the reasons it's popular.

## Also related

[Why choose Craft Commerce over Magento](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/18813/why-choose-craft-commerce-over-magento)